# Opening a new worksheet with the NEXT date

Tags: vba, excel

so I need a macro code for naming a worksheet with the next date on it, as in if the previous sheet is called Tue 27 then the next sheet (new one) should be Wed 28,

my current code only names it as TODAYS date, this is what I am using

```
Dim szTodayDate As String
szTodayDate = Format(Date, "ddd") & Format(Date, " dd")
On Error GoTo MakeSheet
Sheets(szTodayDate).Activate
Exit Sub
MakeSheet:
Dim Srt As Worksheet
Set Srt = ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = szTodayDate
```

Is it even possible to do this, and if so, can anyone please tell me how,
Thank you

additional note: so the macro creates a new sheet everytime I run it, and then names it with todays date, I need it instead to name it with the NEXT date, in relation to the previous sheet. so if the last sheet made (prior to macro run) is called "Sun 02" the macro should create a sheet and name it "Mon 03", assume for now that the month doesn't matter, I will not run this macro after the month ends, so on workbook Feb, "Wed 28" would be the last time I run this macro.

Reason Explained: so I need to create a new worksheet everyday for work, but I sometimes end up having to make the worksheet a day later, so lets say on sun 02 I make the sheet on time, so now I have worksheet sun 02, but then I miss it on monday, then on tuesday I make the sheet, it ends up making Sheet Tue 04, so now I'm missing Mon 03.

Possible Alternate: If I could somehow set an IF function that can check to see if worksheet with yesterdays name exists (maybe going back upto 2 days) and if not create it, that would work to. but not sure how to code said IF function either (It would also need to create it and name it as today, if today is 01).

Thank you again

Comment: Have you already created the sheet and you want to rename it based on the last sheet's name?

Comment: `szTodayDate = Format(Date + 1, "ddd") & Format(Date + 1, " dd")`

Comment: format$(date + 1, "ddd dd") is tomorrow if thats what your asking.  If you want to do this on the fly for any date based on the last sheet name, what month would you use?

Comment: If the latest sheet is "Wed 28", is the next sheeet "Thur 01", as in February, or "Thur 29", as in March?  Not to mention Leap Years!  If you had the Month and Year in there then you could loop through the `.Worksheets` collection for the max Date in `.Name`, using `CDate` to convert text to date, and add 1 to that.  Also, `Format(Date + 1, "ddd") & Format(Date + 1, " dd")` is the same as `Format(Date + 1, "ddd dd")`

Comment: it would be Thu 29, ignore the month change, when the month changes I will switch the workbook. and yes, for on the fly, so if I have a sheet thats already sun 02 then the next sheet needs to be mon 03. (the issue is, sometimes I end up creating a new sheet on the next day, so I end up creating a sheet on tue 04, so my current code creates sheet tue 04, which means I have to manually change the name)

Comment: I see, so CDate can help me go through the worksheet and find the max date, so I should be able to name the activesheet with the date right after that?, how would a code for that look? @Chronocidal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important note for the following code: in its default state it requires that the Sheet Names include the Month, so the format is `"ddd dd mmm"` ("Wed 28 Feb") *not* `"ddd dd"` ("Wed 28").  If, for example, the Month is stored in the FileName instead then you will need to modify the code.

We need a variable to store the most recent date found, and a Worksheet object to use in a `For Each` loop.  We will check each Worksheet's `Name` and check if it `IsDate`.  If it is, then we will see if it is later than our currently stored Date.  **This will fail at year end**, unless you start including the Year in the Sheet Name (or File Name) too.  (Since `1 Jan` comes before `31 Dec`)

```
Dim dMaxDate AS Date, wsForLoop AS Worksheet, sTestString AS String

dMaxDate = DateSerial(1900,1,0) 'Default to 0

For Each wsForLoop In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'Loop through every worksheet
    sTestString = wsForLoop.Name 'Get the name of the sheet
    If InStr(sTestString, " ") > 0 Then sTestString = Mid(sTestString, 1+InStr(sTestString, " ")) 'Remove the Weekday

    'If you need to add the Month/Year from your filename, do that here

    If IsDate(sTestString) Then 'Only check Worksheets with Dates for Names
        If cDate(sTestString) > dMaxDate Then dMaxDate = cDate(sTestString) 'If this is a later date then store it
    End If
Next wsForLoop 'Return to start of loop

If dMaxDate < DateSerial(1900, 1, 1) Then dMaxDate = Now-1 'If we have no Worksheets with Dates for Names then default to yesterday

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'Add a new sheet
    'Change the Format if you are adding the Month and/or Year from Filename
    .Name = Format(dMaxDate+1, "ddd d mmm") 'And Name it the day after our stored date
End With
```

Comment: I tried running the macro, but its showing compile error : syntax error for dMaxDate = Date (1990,1,0) ' Default to 0

Comment: Sorry, should be `DateSerial(1900,1,0)` - `Date` is for Excel formula XP

Comment: YES! this is perfect, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: actually, there is one last issue I'm having, the start date seems to be from Jan, is it possible to change the start month to say, Febuary or March

Comment: by the way, just out of curiosity, wouldn't it be possible (and maybe easier) to set it so, IF a worksheet name exists with date-2 then check Date-1, or name active sheet Date-2. if not check Date-1, ending with Today?  but also start the IF function only if Today(dd) is not 1(start of the month, because I run the macro on a new workbook every month) (because honestly a 2 day test should be enough)

Comment: Rather than checking for worksheets "Date-1", "Date-2", etc, it loops through all worksheets looking for ones with dates, and only remembers later dates.  If no worksheets have dates for names, then it *should* default to creating today's date - put a breakpoint the `If dMaxDate < 1 Then` line if this is giving problems and run `?dMaxDate` in the Immediate Window to see what it is giving

Comment: I think I'm messing up somewhere, still new to all of this, it works perfectly, the last issue is, if there it no worksheets with date for name, it creates is as Jan 1, instead of Today, thank you for being so patient with me on this. (I don't really understand what you meant by put a breakpoint and stuff, sorry)

Comment: actually, it really not an issue, its only one day a month, Thanks again ^_^

Comment: just been running it, ITs proving EVEN more useful as it is, THANK YOU AGAIN, SO MUCH! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

try using below, you can use counter instead of 1.

```
SZTodayDate = Format(Date + 1, "ddd") & Format(Date + 1, " dd")
```